# (Java) Efficiency in my Starter Bubble Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, foreach, bubble-sort

I am new to Java and I have a question regarding optimization.

How fast is it if I declare before my IF statement a variable that gets the value of `x.indexOf(i) + 1` instead of just putting it twice in my code below (which depicts the first call of a bubblesort, without the recurency).

Is it worth to actually make a `j` variable which holds that `x.indexOf(i) +1` instead of just letting the function run once more?

I also believe that my first condition in the IF is a bit flawed, is it possible to let the `i` start at a `i+1` value in a foreach?

Also the use of ArrayList is mandatory.

Thanks for the answers. (Haven't read yet the Coding Standard in Java so I guess it looks ugly)

```
public static void bubbleOnce(ArrayList<Integer> x) {
        for(int i : x) {
            if((x.indexOf(i) != x.size()-1) && i > x.get(x.indexOf(i) + 1)) {
             Collections.swap(x, x.indexOf(i), (x.indexOf(i) + 1));       
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the JIT-Compiler uses [Common Subexpression Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination), so there should be no notable difference. But if in doubt, try it yourself.

Comment: using indexOf in a loop is a bad idea. Your loop is O(n^2), instead of O(n).

Comment: There are several performance errors here. The JIT will properly optimize the code being executed at runtime, but slow algorithms will be slow no matter the optimizations that can be done at runtime. I would suggest you to use `List#get` rather than `List#indexOf` to solve this issue and think a bit more about the algorithm you're currently using.

Comment: @Turing85 The compiler would have to "know" that method x.size() has no side effect changing x.indexOf(i). So I don't think it can use a single call.

Comment: @laune true. Forgot about that minor detail for a second.

Comment: @laune That's true, but there are chances it inlines both methods and then it does know. As long as the call site stays monomorphic, it can do the inlining and easily see that there are no writes. But I'm unsure if it's smart enough to understand `indexOf` good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `indexOf` is not correct, if your `ArrayList x` contains more than one value of `i`, your sort method will behave incorrectly.

For example, this case: `[5, 5, 1]`

After running your program, return `[5, 5, 1]`

Plus, using `indexOf`, as mentioned by tucuxi, will slow down your program.

Comment: Not to mention that it is incredibly slow too. Applying this to 1M-element arrays would take forever...

Comment: @tucuxi as if that would matter when using bubble sort ;)

Comment: O(n³) is much worse than O(n^2). Having such a performance sink in a question on efficiency is quite the irony.

Comment: @tucuxi I know. It was a joke poking at O(n^2) compared to O(n log(n))

Comment: @PhamTrung Why do you use while?

Comment: @laune remove it, I realized that OP called the function `bubbleOnce`, so it is not the whole bubble sort.

Comment: @Pham Thung i know that it won't work on duplicate numbers. Also thanks for the awnsers.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for the Common Subexpression Elimation link, I am going to read about it. I am new to stack overflow and can't figure out how can I give you the approved awnser since you just commented.

Comment: @CristiDragomir I did not provide an answer, just a comment. Also, the comment of mine was partially wrong (see laune's comment). [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how and when to accept an answer.